# Left-speaker volume is very small in some applications

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, speakers

Specifically, when using VLC, gnome Videos to open a sound file, both speakers have the same volume. If I use any of Rhymthmbox, Banshee or Clementine, the left speaker volume is very small.

Both speakers volume are similar when I tested with the `Test Speaker` tool in `System Settings`. Also, the system recognizes them speakers as headphones in output device.

Comment: Did you try changing the balance of the speakers in, say, alsamixer or pulseaudio?

Comment: Yes @Patrick Negus, tried both in terminal and gui they said elsewhere, all showed that the two speakers volume are equal. I think it's true, as it works well with VLC.